# How to automate SAS EG 4.1 program daily and put the output in Excel and run VBA and print PDF?

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file, automation, sas

I am totally new to automation, but trying hard to find answers online everywhere for 1 week. I could not able to do what I wanted to do. I have a SAS enterprise guide 4.1 old version and program runs on a SAS server. I have a SAS report due every day at 9:30 AM. I have the code that is already setup and working fine. I need to automate this program to run at 8:00 AM every day, then move the output to a specific excel file in sheet 1 at specific cell range, then invoke the VBA macro button (UPDATE) placed in the sheet 2 and then print out two worksheets in the same file as a single PDF file to somewhere in my computer. I will have to upload this into a CMS. I wanted to automate until the step before the last step, creating the final PDF report on a daily basis.

When I thought about all these I was stunned. I actually created a batch file in notepad and made SAS to open the file at specific time using Task Scheduler in Windows XP control panel. However, SAS did not run the program.

Here is the batch file code:
**Start/w C:\PROGRA~1\SAS\ENTERP~1\SEGuide.exe –sysin "Z:\ccccc\vvvvv\Report.egp"**

If anyone could please help me, I would like to know how do I make the SAS to run the program in the SAS server and also where do I provide the user name and password for the SAS server authentication. Can anyone please give me an example how to write this code in my batch file. Also, how to export the output into the specific excel file in SHEET 1 and then run the VBA macro. Then how to print out PDF files of two worksheets as a single file and place the final PDF file in the C:\Report folder.

I am sorry it is too much information, but if someone could help me figure out, I would really appreciate all your help!

Park

Answer (score 2):

Enterprise Guide automation is a bigger issue than can be covered in a StackOverflow answer in detail.  In general, EG exposes itself to automation through a DLL (SASEGScripting.dll), which you can then automate using VBScript, Powershell, or .NET (C# etc.).  You need to read the documentation for the API or read a tutorial.

Chris Hemedinger has several good explanations of how to go about doing this; for example, see [this article](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/guide/examples/SASGF2012/Hemedinger_298-2012.pdf), or browse his [blog articles](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/).

Comment: Thanks Joe! I am just learning programming and I am wondering if I can at least code in the windows batch file to make the SAS code run and output into a file. I am sure this can be done with a simple 2-3 line code added into my above batch file. As I can open the SAS program at certain time and also the EGP file, but not able to run the program. Should I have to use .sas file instead? If so, how do I code for the sas server authentication, user name and password? Thanks again!

Comment: Well, you could read the article I linked to.  That answers all of those questions.